# Client/Server java trouble - Client send multiple message when reconnect on server

Tags: java, user-interface, server, chat

i'm new in programming and as far as I succeed to open my server and connect my client on it. It appear that when im disconnecting my client with my actionPerformed, and try to reconnect, the message is send twice. If I do it again and reconnect a third time, the message is send 3 times. But if I close the app and start it new, no problem.
Thank you for your help.

Here's my client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import Control.fenetre;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Client implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private static Socket          socket   = null;
    private static DataInputStream streamIn =  null;
    private static DataOutputStream streamOut = null;
    private Thread thread = null;
    boolean quitRequest = false;
    int portSet;
    String nickName;
    String hostName;
    public Client (String nickName, String hostName, int portSet) {
        fenetre.boutonR1.addActionListener(this);
        fenetre.fermerConnexion.addActionListener(this);
        this.nickName = nickName;
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.portSet = portSet;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(hostName, portSet);
            start();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            fenetre.statusBar.setText("Error.");
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        while (thread != null && quitRequest==false) {
        try {
            open();
            boolean done = false;
            while (!done) {
                try {
                    String line = streamIn.readUTF();
                    fenetre.area.setText(fenetre.area.getText() + "\n\n"+line);
                    done = line.equals(".quit");
                    fenetre.statusBar.setText("Message recu");
                    fenetre.boiteVide();
                }
                catch(IOException ioe)  {
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            fenetre.statusBar.setText("Connexion denied.");
        }
      }
    }
    public void start() {  
        if (thread == null) {  
        thread = new Thread(this); 
        thread.start();
      }
   }
    public void open() throws IOException {
        streamIn = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == fenetre.boutonR1) {
            try {
                streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                streamOut.writeUTF(nickName+"\n" +fenetre.area.getText());
                streamOut.flush();
                fenetre.statusBar.setText("Message sent.");
            }
            catch (IOException e1) {
                fenetre.statusBar.setText("Connexion issue.");
                fenetre.boiteVide();
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == fenetre.fermerConnexion) {
            try {
                close();
                fenetre.statusBar.setText("Closing the connexion.\n");
                fenetre.boiteVide();
            }
            catch (IOException ieo) {
                fenetre.statusBar.setText("Fail.");
            }
        }
    }
    public void close() throws IOException {
        quitRequest = true;
        if (socket != null)    socket.close();
        if (streamIn != null)  streamIn.close();
        if (streamOut != null) streamOut.close();
    }
}
```

I open my reconnexion with this:

```
private void ouvrirFil() {
        Client porteClient = null;
        porteClient = new Client(nickName, hostName, portSet);
}
```

Comment: You must be attaching your listener more than once.

Comment: That's exactly that, everytime im creating an object im adding a actionlistener to my button! Thanks man!